# Singleton with read-only and write access

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a class `T` and want a single global object of that class given by accessor functions like `T const& read_singleton()` and `T& modify_singleton()`. The object should be instantiated at first use of one of these functions by the default constructor of `T` and the usage of the functions should be thread-safe. What is a (good) design pattern to achieve this?

Comment: It's not so easy if you want thread safe implementation to avoid data race and memory leak. Presentation on the topic --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVBvHbJsg5Y

Comment: Should thread-safety not be huge concern since c++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to write these functions:

```
T& modify_singleton()
{
    T static t{};
    return t;
}

T const& read_singleton()
{
    return modify_singleton();
}
```

This is the Meyers singleton pattern and can also be implemented as static functions of `T`, in case you have control over its implementation and want to make its constructor/destructor and such private.

The initialisation of variable `t` will be thread-safe. However, what happens when multiple threads obtain a `T&` is outside the control of `modify_singleton`. You will have to coordinate modifications to the object, either with a global mutex or by designing its class to be thread-safe. If you cannot modify class `T`, you could also provide a thread-safe interface through a wrapper class.